# Upscaling big images

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have created live wallpaper recently. It does displays two images next to each other. Each image does take half of width of screen. When moving the screens (moving to sides on home screen) images does move too.

I wanted it to look as good as possible, so **all my background images does have resolution 1320x958**. I know the height isn't right ideal, but that was the best I was able to get from most of the images I used.

On wallpaper start, images are scaled to screen height and appropriate width is calculated. It does run good on devices with smaller displays (ldpi, mdpi).
The problem are devices with big screens, where there is a need to upscale (not downscale) my images, suddenly I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. I got crash report from Samsung S3, I dont understand how could this happen on devices with big screens (which have more memory available) when older devices with smaller screens (and less memory) doesn't have any problem.

Here is my code:

```
private void InitializeBackgrounds()
{
    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();

    // Load and scale backgrounds
    int bg_height = height;
    int bg_width = (int)((float)bg_height/958.0f*1320.0f);

    try {
        // Load random image from array of images
        Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, left_files[r.nextInt(left_files.length)]);
        // Scale image to new size
        spurs = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, bg_width, bg_height, true);
        // Free up memory immediately
        original.recycle();

        // Do the same for right image
        original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, right_files[r.nextInt(right_files.length)]);
        heat = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, bg_width, bg_height, true);
        original.recycle();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
        throw new OutOfMemoryError("OutOfMemoryException;InitializeBackgrounds(); model: " + Build.MODEL + "; LocalizedMessage: "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"; Message: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Later, when drawing, loaded images are cropped to fit the width of screen. There is created effect of moving images when moving screens. That is why I have loaded image that is bigger than screen in memory.

```
private void drawWallpaper(Canvas c)
{
    // ...
    try {
        bg_left = Bitmap.createBitmap(spurs, x_shift, 0, width/2, height);
        bg_right = Bitmap.createBitmap(heat, x_shift, 0, width/2, height);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
          throw new OutOfMemoryError("OutOfMemoryException;DrawWallpaper(); model: " + Build.MODEL + "; LocalizedMessage: "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"; Message: "+e.getMessage());
    }

    // Draw backgrounds
    c.drawBitmap(bg_left, 0, 0, null);
    c.drawBitmap(bg_right, width/2, 0, null);  

    //...
}
```

Could you help me optimize my code?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to draw bitmap using transformation matrix, but its slow. Here is how I tried it:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.reset();
RectF rect_source = new RectF(x_shift, 0, source_width, original_height);
RectF rect_destination = new RectF(0, 0, width/2, height);
m.setRectToRect(rect_source, rect_destination, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
c.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resource_left), m, null);
```

It doesn't fit my screen as it should (I must made error in computing sizes). Is it right way? May it be quicker when fix computations (will crop lower area)?

Comment: dont use createScaledBitmap, just setup right Matrix and call c.drawBitmap(b, matrix, paint)

Comment: I gave it a quick try, but its too slow (maybe because I wrongly created matrix). I need to recrop and redraw image on every `onOffsetsChanged()` event and need it to be smooth

Comment: how did you create a matrix?

Comment: c.drawBitmap
(BitmapFactory.
decodeResource(res,
resource_left), m, null);

dont decode resource each time you have to draw

Comment: Well then there are only two options, keep in memory original big resource (keen resolve in `OutOfMemoryError`), or scale the resource to needed size using `createScaledBitmap` which you didn't recommend.

Comment: ooops, i though you need both bitmaps at one time, thats why i sugested to keep only the source one and use matrix for drawing. if you need ro load huge image but draw it much smaller see optional parameter Opts when using BitmapFactory.decode* methods, http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: ok seems that on small devices you need to scale down and on big devices dont scale up but use matrix instead...:)